# Autofac DI in parallel.foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to use autofac with a parallel foreach. I've created a new Lifetime scope inside the parallel foreach. But when I access an injected EF repository from within the foreach it's throwing an object not set to an instance of an object exception.

```
using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
    {
         using (var parallelScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope())
         {
             var aDataService = parallelScope.Resolve<IaDataService>();
             someProcessing(aDataService);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: can you show the object registrations?

Comment: Is `scope` thread safe?

Comment: builder.RegisterType<aDataService>().As<IaDataService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<aDataRepository>().As<IaDataRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Comment: How can I check if scope is thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application code should not have to know about creating scopes and having to deal with parallelization. So the Parallel.ForEach should be part of your composition root, and so should be any calls to `BeginLifetimeScope`. Besides this, don't use a lifetime scope as parent scope for creating new scopes in new threads; the new thread is a new context, and should create the scope directly from the container.

So this is code that should be part of your Composition Root:

```
Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
{
     // Note I'm calling container.BeginLifetimeScope() inside the ForEach
     using (var parallelScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
     {
         var aDataService = parallelScope.Resolve<IaDataService>();
         aDataService.SomeProcessing();
     }
 }
```